# htaccess - How to rewrite all requests to a sub directory file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need some help to have my .htaccess to rewrite all request to a subdirectory file. I've search over stackoverflow but all examplex are to rewrite to a subdirectory only...

```
-app
-src
-vendors
-web
  -img
  -css
  -js
  -index.php
```

I tought this would have done the job but it seems not :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/index.php/$1 [L]
```

What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Do you have `RewriteEngine On` at top. Can you post your complete .htaccess here?

Comment: Yep, I will update mon question

Comment: Do you have another .htaccess in `/web/` directory?

Comment: Well I tried both with no success.. 

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]`

Comment: True but first you need to remove `/web/.htaccess` then try rule in root .htaccess

Comment: yes, I tried and it doesn't work either

Comment: Dump your complete .htaccess from DOCUMENT_ROOT

Comment: It is exactly the one in my question. When I add `[R=302]` the redirect works correctly but I don't want my url to change.

Comment: Do you have any CMS/PHP framework running?

Comment: yes, I use a micro-framework called Silex

Comment: Is that framework installed under `/web/` folder?

Comment: no it is in vendors,app, and src

Comment: Ok replace your rule with this: **`RewriteRule !^web /web/index.php/%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L]`**

Comment: Again, it only works if I use [R=302]

Comment: Do you get 404 otherwise OR some other error?

Comment: As `R` flag tells you that rule is correct, why you're getting 404 is probably because of some local code (framework).